# Can the environment "create-react-app" to work with 2 servers?

Tags: reactjs

I work with create-react-app (npm starts server http://localhost:3000/)

Everything is OK

For data access I'm trying to connect to my server  http://127.0.0.1:8081

My script send a request

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8081/xhr', {method: 'post', body: data, credentials: 'include'})
```

Server 127.0.0.1:8081 receives the request and gives the answer

```
200, 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'OK'
```

But react-js gives an error
***"TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch the resource."***
If I do "npm run build", everything works without error.
But it's uncomfortable.

There is a solution to the environment "create-react-app" worked just 2 servers (localhost:3000 and 127.0.0.1:8081) ?